# cylinder shape around an arbitary curve

Tags: geometry, differential-geometry, vectors, curves

I am trying to find an analytic way to describe a cable (like a cylinder) in order to calculate the exact point of intersection of the cable wall with a given ray (straight line) in $\mathbb{R}^3$. Unfortunately I cannot simplify the cable to being straight and I want to describe it as a curve. Are there any parameterizations of bent cylinders following a defined curve?

Thanks!

Comment: You seem to be interested in [tubes](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Tube.html).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up [Frenet frames](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Frenet%E2%80%93Serret_formulas). Given a curve $\vec x(t):\Bbb R\to\Bbb R^3$, there are formulas which yield the vectors $\vec {\mathfrak t}(t)$, $\vec {\mathfrak n}(t)$ and $\vec {\mathfrak b}(t)$, the so called *Frenet frame*. Here $\vec {\mathfrak t}(t)$ is the tangent vector to $\vec x$ at $t$, and the vectors $\vec {\mathfrak n}(t)$ and $\vec {\mathfrak b}(t)$ are perpendicular to this tangent. You can use them to parametrize the tube of radius $r$ around $\vec x$, but this most probably will give no easy formula to deal with analytically:

$$T(s,t)=\vec x(t)+r\cos(2\pi s)\vec{\mathfrak n}(t)+r\sin(2\pi s)\vec{\mathfrak b}(t).$$

[image]

Also there are some restrictions on $\vec x$ to guarantee the existence of the Frenet frame, e.g. the curve is not allowed to have points of zero curvature.

---

For your application I would reccomend you just using an optimization strategy to  find the minimal distance between a ray $\vec r$ and your curve $\vec x$, e.g. repeated binary search or gradient descent to avoid getting trapped in local minima. If this distance is smaller than the radius of your cable, then there will be an intersection at this point.

Comment: The Frenet frame is not absolutely necessary for this; you only require two unit vectors orthogonal to the tangent and to each other. For example, if you know the tangent is never parallel to a unit vector $u$, then you can choose $u$ and $t\times u$. This way you can handle linear segments as well, where the Frenet frame is not defined.

Comment: @Rahul Absolutely right. And thank you for explaning the "other cases". I was just looking for a quick way to yield orthogonal vectors. There were certainly other ways.

Comment: Thank you, this is indeed very helpful, especially with your explanation. Just for clarification of the cases where I cannot use frenet frames: For example if I had a half circle in the $z=0$ plane?

Comment: @W21 In this case use the hint of Rahul. Then choose $\vec{\mathfrak n}(t)=(0,0,1)^\top$ and $\vec{\mathfrak b}(t)=\vec{\mathfrak n}(t)\times \vec{\mathfrak t}(t)$. However, I read your comment to the other answer and I must tell you that there is indeed a much simpler way to handle the problem without constructing the surface even *with* all these other results you need. This is a classical example of the [XY-Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). I recommend you starting a new question and asking for your initial problem.

Comment: @Rahul _"if you know the tangent is never parallel to a unit vector $u$, then you can choose $u$ and $t \times u$"_ but it is insufficient for $u$ never to be parallel tot $t$ but it has also to be orthogonal, hasn't it?

Comment: @W21 You are right about your comment on Rahuls hint.

Comment: @M.Winter You might be right. I will formulate my initial problem and post a new question about it. Thank you for the advice!

Comment: @W21: Oops, you're right. I meant $v = \operatorname{normalize}(t\times u)$ and $w = \operatorname{normalize}(v\times t)$, where $\operatorname{normalize}(x)=x/\|x\|$.

Comment: Hey @M.Winter, I have spend some time studying some fundamentals of differential geometry and the Frenet frame. Now, I do not understand why the curve is not allowed to be planar. If it is planar, I have no torsion. But with or without, I can create the vectors of the Frenet frame. The only problem there would be is, that they aren't explicit (not sure if that's the right term) for every point, or am I wrong?

Comment: @W22 You are absolutely right. I will edit my answer as soon as I have time. Only thing is that if the curve is a line, there is no unique way to choose a Frenet frame.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you are overthinking this. The intersection occurs when the distance between the curve and the ray is less than $r$. So the condition is

$$ \| {\rm curve}(t) - {\rm ray}(s) \| \le r $$

Without any further details, it is difficult to go any further. This is equivalent to placing an infinite number of spheres of radius $r$ along the curve and finding which one intersects the ray.

Comment: Thank you, this would be indeed a simple to deal with the Problem. The further details to this problem would be, that I have to calculate the angle at the intersection (angle of surface tangent plane at the point and the ray). I think for this there will be no other way then to explicitly define a surface?